# Using a Do-loop to find divisors mod 13

Tags: core-language, number-theory

I want to check sum of divisors of `i` mod 13 for`i = 1` to `i = 2`0. I tried writing a Do-Print loop so it looks like

```
Do[Print[DivisorSigma[1, i], {i, 20} mod 13]
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Table[DivisorSigma[1, i], {i, 20} ] // Mod[#, 13] &
(*{1, 3, 4, 7, 6, 12, 8, 2, 0, 5, 12, 2, 1, 11, 11, 5, 5, 0, 7, 3}*)
```

or

```
Do[Print[Mod[DivisorSigma[1, i], 13]], {i, 20}]
```

which gives a column of the same numbers as before that you can look at, but it is more difficult use in further expressions.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without iterators because the functions you need (`Mod`, `DivisorSigma`) are [`Listable`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html):

```
Mod[DivisorSigma[1, Range[20]], 13]
```

> {1, 3, 4, 7, 6, 12, 8, 2, 0, 5, 12, 2, 1, 11, 11, 5, 5, 0, 7, 3}

**Note:** `Listable` functions are applied separately to each element in a list.

Comment: that's also very useful and helpful thank you